# Ansible looping into a list of dictionnary

Tags: loops, ansible

newbie in ansible I'm trying unsucessfully to loop through my group var I'm not sure of my variable structure

group_vars/myvar

```
filedata:
  - file1:
    information:
      - path: "/tmp"
      - filename: "*.log"
      - retention: "+30"
  - file2:
    information:
      - path: "/var/log"
      - filename: "*.lg"
      - retention: "+10"
```

I'm trying to loop through this for having path filename and retention in a simple playbook

```
---
- name: loop test
  host: myvar
  gather_facts: false
  task:
  - name: loop
    debug:
      msg: "fileid={{ item.key }}"
    loop: "{{ filedata | dict2items }}"
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Your `filedata` variable looks incorrect, what is `file1` and `file2` ? why there isn't a `:` after it?

Comment: I want to use it as an identifier, i forgot to reput the : after a test

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here. First, your example isn't a valid playbook; attempting to run it will result in:

```
ERROR! 'host' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

It's always a good idea to make sure that the code you post is *syntactically* correct, because that way we can focus on your actual question.

---

Second, your data structure, while syntactically valid, isn't going to be useful. You've defined an item in your list like this:

```
file1:
information:
  - path: "/tmp"
  - filename: "*.log"
  - retention: "+30"
```

In the above, `file1` is a key whose value is an empty dictionary. I would suggest you modify your data structure so that you have this (if you want a list):

```
filedata:
  - name: file1:
    information:
      - path: "/tmp"
      - filename: "*.log"
      - retention: "+30"
  - name: file2:
    information:
      - path: "/var/log"
      - filename: "*.lg"
      - retention: "+10"
```

Or like this (if you want a dictionary):

```
filedata:
  file1:
    information:
      - path: "/tmp"
      - filename: "*.log"
      - retention: "+30"
  file2:
    information:
      - path: "/var/log"
      - filename: "*.lg"
      - retention: "+10"
```

---

If we correct the syntax errors in your playbook, we get:

```
TASK [loop] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ filedata | dict2items }}): dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'list'> instead."}
```

That error message seems pretty clear. You've defined `filedata` as a list (of dictionaries); the `dict2items` filter is for converting **from** a dictionary **to** a list.

If we assume the first version ("..if you want a list") of the data structure, we can write:

```
- name: loop test
  hosts: myvar
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: loop
    debug:
      msg: "fileid={{ item.name }}"
    loop: "{{ filedata }}"
```

Which gets us as output:

```
TASK [loop] ********************************************************************
ok: [node0] => (item={'name': 'file1', 'information': [{'path': '/tmp'}, {'filename': '*.log'}, {'retention': '+30'}]}) => {
    "msg": "fileid=file1"
}
ok: [node0] => (item={'name': 'file2', 'information': [{'path': '/var/log'}, {'filename': '*.lg'}, {'retention': '+10'}]}) => {
    "msg": "fileid=file2"
}
```

If instead we use the dictionary version, we can then use `dict2items` and write this:

```
- name: loop test
  hosts: myvar
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: loop
    debug:
      msg: "fileid={{ item.key }}"
    loop: "{{ filedata|dict2items }}"
```

Which produces the (remarkably similar) output:

```
TASK [loop] ********************************************************************
ok: [node0] => (item={'key': 'file1', 'value': {'information': [{'path': '/tmp'}, {'filename': '*.log'}, {'retention': '+30'}]}}) => {
    "msg": "fileid=file1"
}
ok: [node0] => (item={'key': 'file2', 'value': {'information': [{'path': '/var/log'}, {'filename': '*.lg'}, {'retention': '+10'}]}}) => {
    "msg": "fileid=file2"
}
```